# Css - Select Option (with background image) padding-left or text-indent issue on IE

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a problem with select input to be properly displayed on Internet Explorer, though it works well on Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

Select option goes all the way down to the left and should have 60px of left padding as on chrome, safari and firefox.

Please test it on the jsfiddle that I prepared. Could you help please?

HTML

```
<div id="form-selector">    
<select name='someinput' id='someinput' class="form-control img-input">
<option value="" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#form-selector select {
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background:#fff;
  margin-bottom:14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#000000;
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
}

// Firefox Fix
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
#form-selector select {
   text-indent: 30px;
} }


.img-input { 
background:url(http://placehold.it/60x30) no-repeat left center #ffffff !important;
  padding-left:60px; }
```

JS FIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/02uj91gp/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following hack on IE: (i'm using IE 11)

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
     #form-selector select {
  padding-left: 60px;
}
}
```

Updated JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/02uj91gp/16/

I would appriciate if someone could check it on Safari, Edge 12 and older versions of IE than 11. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the bugs caused by `text-indent` in IE, you can use `padding-left`, which works in all browsers :)

```
#form-selector select {
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  background:#fff;
  margin-bottom:14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#000000;
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
}
```

Note that you will also need to remove the Firefox-specific fix you added, as this is no longer necessary:

```
// Firefox Fix
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
#form-selector select {
   text-indent: 30px;
} }
```

I've created a new fiddle showcasing this working correctly in all browsers [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wfrgyLg7/1).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: So it should but is not. Check Firefox please!

Comment: That's because of the additional Firefox-specific indentation that you added, which is no longer necessary. Just remove that and it will work in Firefox -- https://jsfiddle.net/wfrgyLg7/1/. I've just updated my answer to cover this (and show the new link) :)

Comment: this was my  starting point before i asked this question. Now can anyone check it on Safari. I have no acces to Mac at the time, and with these css setting i had a problem with Safari.Once i fixed Safari, problem with IE showed up.

Comment: Safari, along with all other browsers, should handle `padding-left` correctly, whereas `text-indent` has been known to cause problems.

Comment: I was using padding-left at the beginning just to find out there is an issue in safari. Did you check in Safari?

Comment: I don't have access to a Mac myself, though it seems as though there are indeed issues with padding in Safari. You might be able to get around that with `-webkit-appearance:none;` in combo with `padding-left`, or alternatively get around the `text-indent` issue by specifying a `line-height`. Browsers all seem to have individual quirks that make it difficult to get cross-compatibility in situations like this. However, your **question** was how to make it work in IE.

Comment: Exactly mate. Thanks for looking into it. Once you go with -webkit-appearance:nonel fix then select buttons do not show, and this is not a solution.